Ensuring appropriate accuracy in integration over infinite sums
I would like to be able to evaluate, numerically, the function $f(n, a, w)$ shown below so that I can:

integrate $f(n, a, w)$ over the range $[0 \le p \le 1]$ for various positive integer $n < 50$  real $0 < a < 5$ (I'm particularly interested in the range $1/50 < a < 3/2$ );

graphically explore the relationship between the value of the integral and $w$ for the those same values of $n$ and $a$;

estimate, within about $0.005$, the value of $w$ that minimizes the integral for the same $n$ and $a$.


I have more experience with Mathematica's symbolic capabilities than with the numerical side . Given the oscillatory nature of $f$, and the infinite sums (which are fortunately moderated by the fact that the negative exponential is going to decay rapidly), I'd appreciate guidance as to the overall approach (in terms of functions and options) to ensure the accuracy I'm looking for.
Function
$$
\begin{align}
f(n, a, w) &= \frac{1}{n} \left(w^2+\frac{a^2}{12}+4 \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \left((-1)^k \exp \left(-\frac{2
   k^2 \pi ^2 w^2}{a^2}\right) \left(w^2+\frac{a^2}{4 k^2 \pi ^2}\right) \cos
   \left(\frac{2 \pi  p k}{a}\right)-\frac{a^2}{\pi
   ^2}  S^2\right)\right) \\ &-\left(p+\frac{a}{\pi } S \right)^2-\frac{2 p
   }{n} \left(p+\frac{a S}{\pi }\right)+p^2
\end{align}
$$
where
$$
S = \sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^j }{j} \: \exp \left(-\frac{2 j^2 \pi ^2
   w^2}{a^2}\right) \sin \left(\frac{2 j \pi  p}{a}\right)
$$
Mathematica code

F[n_, a_, w_] :=     (1/n) * (w^2 + a^2/12 +
4 * Sum[(-1)^k * Exp[-((2 * k^2 * Pi^2 * w^2)/a^2)] *
(w^2 + a^2/(4 * k^2 * Pi^2)) *
Cos[(2 * Pi * p * k)/a] - (a^2/Pi^2) * S^2,
{k, 1, Infinity}]) - (p + (a/Pi) * S)^2 - ((2 * p)/
n) * (p + (a/Pi) * S) + p^2

with

S = Sum[((-1)^j/j) * Exp[-((2 * j^2 * Pi^2 * w^2)/a^2)] * Sin[(2 * j * Pi * p)/a],{j, 1, Infinity}]

Edited: Following the suggestion of @Bill, I have changed the variable of summation in $S$ to $j$ for the sake of clarity.

I am concerned about clarity when you use k as your iterator in both Sum Could you change one of those to j? After that could you perhaps tackle a possibly simpler problem and try to get an accurate numerical approximation for just your S? That might show you a few things and possibly make it easier to find your larger Sum

Suggest you first study the two sums over the range of variables you wish in order to first obtain some sense of their accuracy as a function of summation index (via table of values and plots perhaps):  what value of $k$ gives you 10 digits of accuracy (numerically) and so forth, then will have handle on accuracy of f.

For example You can start with:
ClearAll["`*"]; Remove["`*"]

P[n_, a_, w_, M_] := NIntegrate[(1/n)*(w^2 + a^2/12 + 
                     4*Sum[(-1)^k*Exp[-((2*k^2*Pi^2*w^2)/a^2)]*(w^2 + a^2/(4*k^2*Pi^2))*
                     Cos[(2*Pi*p*k)/a] - (a^2/Pi^2)*S^2, {k, 1, M}]) - (p + (a/
                     Pi)*S)^2 - ((2*p)/n)*(p + (a/Pi)*S) + p^2 /. 
                     S -> Sum[((-1)^j/j)*Exp[-((2*j^2*Pi^2*w^2)/a^2)]*
                     Sin[(2*j*Pi*p)/a], {j, 1, M}], {p, 0, 1}, 
                     Method -> "GaussKronrodRule", WorkingPrecision -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 10];

P[10, 2, 2, 10](*For example: n=10, a=2, w=2, M=10 terms.*)

(*0.366667*)

Plot[P[10, 2, w, 10], {w, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All] // Quiet

(*Nice plot *)


Please could you comment on the factors that motivated your choice of GaussKronrodRule as the non-default method for NIntegrate. I also note that you have left things like PrecisionGoal unspecified while that was, for example, one of the things that I was unsure whether I should be manipulating.

@CrimsonDark By default or using method GaussKronrodRule MMA give the same answer.The choice of this method was purely random and I did not take any factors into account.The precision of the calculations depends on the terms in  the series,we can't use infinity for numeric calculation, right?

To solve this problem, we can use numerical function defined as follows
int[km_?NumericQ, jm_?NumericQ, n_?NumericQ, w_?NumericQ, 
  a_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{p}, 
  S = Sum[((-1)^j/j)*Exp[-((2*j^2*Pi^2*w^2)/a^2)]*
     Sin[(2*j*Pi*p)/a], {j, 1, jm}];
  F = (1/n)*(w^2 + a^2/12 + 
       4*Sum[(-1)^k*
           Exp[-((2*k^2*Pi^2*w^2)/a^2)]*(w^2 + a^2/(4*k^2*Pi^2))*
           Cos[(2*Pi*p*k)/a] - (a^2/Pi^2)*S^2, {k, 1, km}]) - (p + (a/
          Pi)*S)^2 - ((2*p)/n)*(p + (a/Pi)*S) + p^2; 
  NIntegrate[F, {p, 0, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 6, 
   Method -> {{Automatic, "LocalAdaptive"}[[-1]], 
     "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]];

Example of usage same as Mariusz
int[10, 10, 10, 2, 2]
(*0.366667*)

Visualization
Quiet@Plot[
  Evaluate@Table[int[10, 10, 10, w, a], {a, {1/50, 1, 3/2}}], {w, -1, 
   1}, PlotLegends -> Table[Row[{"a = ", a}], {a, {1/50, 1, 3/2}}], 
  PlotRange -> All]


As we can see the minimal value int is around w=0, so we use FindMinimum to catch it, for example,
FindMinimum[int[10, 10, 10, w, 1], {w, 0}]

Out[]= {-0.542059, {w -> -5.80511*10^-10}}

